# One side of the cake rises higher than another

Tags: baking

It doesn’t happen always but at times one side of my cake rises higher than the other side creating a lop sided cake, it is not a dome, but more a problem of uneven rising. I oil the pan, place parchment paper and oil and flour the parchment paper itself. Do you think uneven oiling of the pan could be causing this?

Comment: Uneven heating of the over seems more likely. Please [edit] your question and describe in detail what kind of oven you have and how/where it applies heat.

Comment: As far as I recall (not something I personally stress about) the standard cake decorator approach is to plan on cutting off the top of the cake to remove any unevenness (they also typically flip it, so that side becomes the bottom of the cake as decorated and served.)

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12161/how-can-i-avoid-windswept-muffins-in-a-convection-oven

Comment: Is it a fan oven? My cakes rise towards the fan

Comment: Are you sure that the I've racks are level?   A very wet batter in a larger plan would be more obvious than bread or muffins if this is an issue.  (And it would always be a problem in th same direction.  Of course, a fan in a convection oven would also)

Answer (score 5):

It's probably not due to uneven oiling of the pan.

Assuming you haven't managed to stir your batter so that the baking powder (or other leavening) got distributed primarily on one side of the cake, which sounds pretty impossible, the most likely source of asymmetry would be the oven. Are you sometimes cooking these cakes too close to one of the walls of your oven - I mean off-center in the oven?

Or maybe there is an uneven temperature pattern in there. Not sure how to remedy a situation like that, except for trial and error and noting the positioning when the cakes on occasion do come out even.

Comment: You can rotate pans partway through cooking to help alleviate the problem (assuming a temperature gradient is the root issue)

Comment: @Erica - how to rotate the pan through cooking when we are not supposed to open the oven?

Comment: @Gigili you're not supposed to open the oven all the time, but it's usually ok to quickly open once just to rotate the cake.

Answer (score 2):

### Your oven might not be heating to a uniform temperature.

Simply put, some ovens have spots in them that are warmer than others. If you bake a cake in such an oven, some parts of it will therefore be baked at a higher temperature than other parts. This results in the chemical reactions that occur during cooking occurring at different rates.

If part of your cake is cooking too slowly, the gasses produced by the boiling water and/or your raising agents will escape the batter before it solidifies. If part of it cooks too quickly, the batter will solidify before the gasses have the opportunity to expand it. Either way, that portion of the cake will rise less than a portion of the cake that is cooked at a more optimal temperature.

Comment: Would using no fan setting make a difference?